# VBA Find value and copy consecutive rows based on cell format

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the following code which will look through 4 worksheets to find the first instance of "Slide1" in column A.

```
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim i1 As Integer
    For Each ws In Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        LastRow1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        i1 = 1

        Do While i1 <= LastRow1
            If ws.Range("A" & i1).Value = "Slide1" Then
                ws.Rows(i1 & ":" & i1 + 2).Copy Sheets("Summary").Range("A105")
            On Error Resume Next
            End If
            i1 = i1 + 1
        Loop
    Next
```

This has worked okay, but sometimes the values I need to copy include more than 2 rows.

I would like to include some logic that sets the end row by the last cell in column a that has a specific xlEdgeLeft weight and style (Similar to the below). This is the most unique and consistant format in the mess that I'm trying to clean.

```
.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = 1 AND .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = 4
```

Can someone help me with how I might do this? I think I need to create a new variable that would replace "i1 + 2" that would basically figure out when column A stops having the above xlEdgeLeft formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but play around with this Do-While loop I added to your code and you should be able to get there.

```
Dim copiedRows as Integer
Dim i2 as Integer 
Do While i1 <= LastRow1
    copiedRows = 0
    i2 = i1
    If ws.Range("A" & i1).Value = "Slide1" Then
       Do While ws.Range("A" & i2).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = 1 AND .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = 4
           copiedRows= copiedRows+1
           i2 = i2 + 1
       Loop
       ws.Rows(i1 & ":" & i1 + copiedRows).Copy Sheets("Summary").Range("A105")
       On Error Resume Next
    End If
    i1 = i1 + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

That did the trick. Here is an example of the final. Where the If ws.Range finds the first record and then it finds all records starting in the next row that have the specified border

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim i1 As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer
Dim copiedRows As Integer

For Each ws In Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
LastRow1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
i1 = 1

Do While i1 <= LastRow1
    copiedRows = 0
    i2 = i1
    If ws.Range("A" & i1).Value = "Report" And ws.Range("A" & i1 + 1).Value = "Quarter" Then
       Do While ws.Range("A" & i2 + 1).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = 1 And ws.Range("A" & i2 + 1).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = 4
            i2 = i2 + 1
           copiedRows = copiedRows + 1
       Loop
       ws.Rows(i1 & ":" & i1 + copiedRows).Copy Sheets("Summary").Range("A1")
       On Error Resume Next
    End If
    i1 = i1 + 1
Loop
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it worked! Fyi, these answers won't necessarily always be displayed in this order, so best practice is to respond in a comment. Always valid to answer your own question though. Cheers!